# How to create a folder in github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-flavored-markdown

I am new to github actions and need some help.

I have a readme.md file for a collection of scripts that is 100s of lines long. I want to translate it into different languages using this github action (https://github.com/dephraiim/translate-readme)

But instead of putting all the files it creates into the main directory. I want to create a folder inside my directory and put all these created files in there.

So in the main directory I have all the scripts I've written and one readme.md file. What I want is something like this.

Maindirectory/newreadmefolder/(all the new language readme.md files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A directory can be created this way.:

```
      - name: Create dir
        run: |
          mkdir mydirname
```

This has to be added in `steps` part like in this full action file:

```
name: mkdir example

on:
  push:
    branches: [ '**' ]
  
  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Create dir
        run: |
          mkdir mydirname
```

If you also want to move some file, you can add something like `mv readme-*.md mydirname` at the end, e.g.:

```
      - name: Create dir
        run: |
          mkdir mydirname
          mv readme-*.md mydirname
```

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense here, but note that it will also be necessary to commit and push the code to the repository, for the folder to appear there after the workflow execution.

Comment: @GuiFalourd  what do you mean?  Because no folder is appearing using the steps listed above.

Comment: It will appear, but won't persist on the repository if you don't commit and push what has been created during the workflow run.